# How is the first 'page' of a tabbed layout represented on a sitemap?

Tags: navigation, information-architecture, tabs, sitemap

I understand that tabbed navigation is a lateral pattern, but I'm unclear on how this is represented on a sitemap? Is the first tab visualized as a parent screen to the adjacent tabs because it is what loads when the user navigates to the 'Pets' page?

I think I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be — please help!

[image: Sample layout]

[image: Sample corresponding sitemap visual]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're right, you are making it more complicated than it needs to be. :) Pets is the category, and all the tabs should be under that same category. Someone would not go to the "Dogs" section for info about cats!

If I understand correctly, I think the confusion is coming from the fact that "Pets" has no content of its own, and it just defaults to the first tab, "Cats." That's okay, the sitemap is about the user finding their way to the information they need, so it just needs to be in the most intuitive form you can make it.

Donna Spencer talks about site maps quite a bit in her *'Practical Guide to Information Architecture,'* available as a [free e-book](https://maadmob.com.au/information-architecture/free-book-practical-ia). You can look at her chapter "Communicating About Content."

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I found the term I was dancing around—default tab!